# Where are commands of the netinstall mini.iso documented?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, documentation, ubuntu-minimal

I've tried to install a new system with the help of a [mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and ran into wireless configuration issues. 
I found it pretty weird that the mini.iso mostly seems to be working fine although despite pretty basic commands like the following:

```
lshw
lspci
lsusb
ifconfig
```

were missing when I tried them from the command line.

This is the extended version of my question:

- Which commands are available on the mini.iso?
- Where can I find documentation about the available console commands?
- Where can I find what software packages are present on the mini.iso?

---

**Update:** (clarification about the question)

To be clear about the question: with "command line" I mean the console that becomes available when you

- perform "manual" configuration steps during setup (like wireless, disk, serial device setup) or
- when you access the menu point "Execute a shell"

The question is specific about the `mini.iso` or `netinstall.iso` as these are provided seemingly without further documentation. This is *not* a question about what is generally available under `busybox` (or any other mini Linux distro). If the shell on the `mini.iso` is based on `busybox`, I'd like to see where this fact is documented.

The question is *not just* about the above four commands. It's about where to get documentation about what is available as commands.

Some years ago, there used to be documentation about this. And documentation about how to configure devices during install. These seem to be gone without replacement.

Comment: I hve no idea what is meant here by "the command line". Two possibilities are the busybox command-line interface available during the installation, or the installed system, but `lspci` is available in both...

Comment: @fkraiem OK, what about the other commands? `lshw` isn't, as far as I can tell. Do you have a list of what's available?

Comment: @fkraiem, I've updated the question to clarify.  You may be correct that `lspci` is available `busybox`. However on the command line from the `mini.iso` it was not. (I've tried all possible combinations `/bin/lspci` `/sbin/lspci` `/usr/bin/lspci` `/usr/sbin/lspci`)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? On a `mini.iso` for Trusty 64 bits, `lspci` is in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @fkraiem, Wily Werwolf or Vivid Vervet. According the documentation of `busybox`, `lspci` is *not* included there. For the normal installation, it is only included in the `pcitools` package.

Comment: `lspci` is indeed not included in Busybox, but (at least on my Trusty image), other programs are included in addition to those built into Busybox, such as `nano` or indeed `lspci`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that "the command line" in this question means the command-line interface one can obtain by pressing left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> or by choosing "Execute a shell" in the installer menu (which can be accessed by pressing Esc). This interface is based on [Busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html), which *"combines tiny versions of many common UNIX utilities into a single small executable"*. As usual, two kinds of commands are available.

- Commands built into the shell. You can get a list of them by typing `help`, and they are documented [here](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html).
- Binaries located in directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. You can see the contents of `PATH` as usual with `echo $PATH`, and list their contents with `ls`.

However here there is a slight complication, because there are also two kinds of binaries.

- The binaries for many basic utilities, such as for example `ping` or `od` are just symlinks to `/bin/busybox`. Here too those commands are built into Busybox and they are documented in the link above. They are usually much more minimalist than the versions of those commands you are used to, in order to save space.
- Other binaries (*i.e.*, those which are not symlinked to `/bin/busybox`) such as for example `nano` are the same as in a normal Ubuntu system. The manual pages are not available in Busybox, but you can consult them on http://manpages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a pretty wild claim that this interface is based on busybox.  Do you have any hint of a documentation - preferably from ubuntu - that would point me into this direction?

Comment: Uh, it has busybox written on it?

Comment: Although maybe it has changed in newer versions, let me look.

Comment: no, busybox was not written anywhere. This would have given enough of a hint. But busybox itself may also be a dead-end: the documentation says: "BusyBox is extremely configurable. This allows you to include only the components you need, thereby reducing binary size." Where can I find documented **which commands exactly** are included in the `mini.iso` distribution?

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: What do you think? did I? **What** did I not get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33495/discussion-between-bogdan-willi-and-fkraiem).

Comment: @fkraiem: I verified your hunch about BusyBox [above](http://askubuntu.com/a/714012/344926) and you're absolutely right for the version I verified: 14.04 Trusty Tahr uses (amongst other things) BusyBox!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

There is no documentation because:

1. Developers hate writing documentation
2. It's kind of self-documenting:

   The [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) can be mounted with:

   ```
   mkdir /media/DVD-ISO
   sudo mount -o loop /tmp/mini.iso /media/DVD-ISO
   ```

   Now you can inspect the data of the iso itself:

   ```
   ll /media/DVD-ISO
   ```

   and it contains a number of files, of which one is of particular interest:

   ```
   -r--r--r-- 2 root root  21M Apr 15  2014 initrd.gz
   ```

   which is a gzip compressed file which we extract like this:

   ```
   cd /media/DVD-ISO/
   mkdir initrd
   cd initrd
   gunzip ../initrd.gz
   ```

   Which finally give us the boot image `initrd` which we extract using:

   ```
   mkdir temp
   cd temp
   sudo cpio -id < ../initrd
   ```

**And now** you have all the updated documentation you need!  (answering your questions one by one)

1. This gives the full list of commands included in the iso: `ll bin&ll sbin&ll usr/local/bin`
2. Just type `man szCommand` where `szCommand` is the command whose documentation you want.
3. See step 1 as there are no additional packages present...

Comment: Someone somewhere decided the ISO would contain these commands and packages. Surely they would have documented that?

Comment: @muru: Ah!  Telepathy!  **;-)** Read [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/714012/revisions) please

Comment: That would be true of usual devs, but this is Debian and Ubuntu we're talking of - higher standards apply. :P

Comment: @muru **:D :D :D** [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: @kos Yup, that's why #3 points to #1!  **;-)**

Comment: @kos True! Answer edited for clarity